# JPA cascade type REMOVE raises SQL error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a spring mvc app in which I have 2 models. Tripstop and item transaction. Following is my tripstop model:

```
   import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="TripStop")
public class TripStopModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="tripstopid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer tripStopId;

    @Column(name="datetime")
    private String tripStopDateTime;

    @Column(name="createts")
    private Date tripStopCreateTime;

    @Column(name="latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name="longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel locationModel;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="SYSTEMUSERID")
    private UserModel userModel;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tripid")
    private TripModel tripModel;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripStopModel", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ItemTransactionModel> itemTransactionModelList;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tid")
    private CircleModel circleModel;
}
```

Following is my item transaction model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="itemTx")
public class ItemTransactionModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="itemTxid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer itemTxId;

    @Column(name="itemcode")
    private String itemCode;

    @Column(name="weight")
    private String weight;

    @Column(name="bagcount")
    private Integer bagCount;   

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tripstopid")
    private TripStopModel tripStopModel;
}
```

Following is the code I am using to delete tripstop:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(tripStopModel);
```

I want that when I delete tripstop, releted records from itemtx should also get deleted. For this I am using cascade type remove.

But none is getting deleted and it is raising following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

tripstopid is foreign key in itemtx table.

Comment: try to give allow null in tripstopid field in the table itemTx

Comment: try setting `tripStopMode.setItemTransactionModelList(null);` and then call `session.delete(tripStopModel);`

Comment: Tried, but not working

Comment: I have posted my full trip stop model. It has some other relationships too.

Comment: What if you use `CascadeType.ALL`?

Comment: Not working with CascadeType.ALL.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Ok, one more try. Since you use Hibernate's `session.delete()`, try annotating the relation with `@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE) `.

Comment: Also, print out the generated SQL statements to verify that this foreign key is actually causing the problems and not some other relation.

Comment: How can we print generated sql statements?

Comment: Put `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>` in hibernate config.

Comment: I am using spring mvc with annotations. There is no hibernate config file. Hibernate mapping is inside model classes.

Comment: @PredragMaric I have printed generated sql from hibernate. It is:

delete from TripStop where tripstopid=?

Comment: But it should delete records from itemtx table first.